# Appropriate to cast string literal to char * in function argument?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, char

I've got a function which receives a `char *` argument:

```
Foo::Foo (char * arg0) {
    ....
}
```

In the original example, a `char[]` is used to pass this value...

```
char bar[] = "Bar";
Instance.foo (bar);
```

...which works fine.

But, I've found that I can pass a string literal, cast as a `char *`, without any warnings from the compiler.

```
Instance.Foo ((char *) "Bar");
```

However, from my reading, it seems that should be avoided - the value of the memory that is pointed to could change.

Is the above statement true ("this should be avoided") or is this appropriate in this situation?

---

*Edit - further research turned up [this article](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/faq-board/86924-faq-difference-between-c-cplusplus-style-casting.html) which addresses my question pretty well...*

Comment: If you're 100% sure the function doesn't modify it, and you can't change the function's signature to show it, `const_cast` is an option. Otherwise, I'd stick to copying it to a new buffer.

Comment: OK. So is my understanding correct, or is there a different reason?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `std::string`s? You won't have any of these problems.

Comment: The reason it works is due to legacy, but modifying the contents of a string literal is undefined behaviour, so you don't want that. I'd expect something like `warning: deprecated conversion from string literal to char *` from GCC.

Comment: Best to change the function signature to accept a `char const *`.

Comment: @Xymostech - working with Win32 API, trying to stick with the program and answer my little niggles at the same time.

Comment: @Steve, It is rather annoying trying to use better types with that. `std::string` doesn't have anything for a `char *` and `std::vector` can, but doesn't include string functions.

Comment: Do you know, or can you find out, why the function defines its parameter as `char * arg0` rather than `const char * arg0`? You mentioned the Win32 API; is the function part of that API? If so, which one is it?

Comment: It's the class name in WNDCLASSEX which requires a LPCTSTR. (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/…). I'm playing with a tutorial that has the signature rewritten slightly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, avoid that.  Now, if your function took a `const char *` there is nothing wrong with calling it with a string literal.

C++ compilers support string-literal to `char *` for backwards compatibility reasons only, and writing to a string literal results in undefined behavior.

When you do `char bar[] = "Bar";` you are doing something fundamentally different (namely initializing an array of 4 characters with the values `{'B', 'a', 'r', '\0'}` that you are free to modify) than when you do `char bar* = "Bar";` (where you are creating a non-`const` pointer to a 4 byte string that you may not modify).

In my opinion, you should never turn a string literal directly into a `char*`, instead put it into a `const char*` then (if you are communicating with a legacy API) explicitly `const_cast<char*>` the `const`ness away, with a comment saying you are talking to a legacy API that has guarantees not to change the `char`s.  The advantage of this is you can search your program for those `const_cast`s when the API is upgraded, or you want to find where the segmentation fault involving writing to a `char*` came from.

One could even wrap the legacy API with `const char*` versions that do the `const_cast` within them.

The absolute worst situation would be having a bunch of `char*`s hanging around, some of them writable, others from string literals.

Answer (score 1):

This should be avoided at almost all cost and only be done if you have to interface with broken legacy API's and only if you have had a look at their source code and made sure they are not writing to the string.

Stay on the safe side of things and copy the string with `strcpy` before you pass it in.

What exactly is evil? Writing to string literals is undefined behavior.

Comment: `Writing to string literals is undefined behavior` - not sure what you mean - can you expand a bit?

Comment: @Steve, String literals are stored in read-only memory. Attempting to modify read-only memory is bad. The undefined behaviour part just means the language isn't responsible for whatever the compiler decides to do. It could format your hard drive if it wanted to.

Comment: Ahhh.  And another ray of light shines through the clouds.  Thanks - time to go back to the books.

Comment: @Steve String literals **might** be stored in read-only memory or subject to whatever optimizations your compiler can concoct. Writing to them has undefined behavior. If you have trouble with that term I suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior